# How do I fix music in my Unity project which randomly bugs when I run the Gameplay scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I recently finished Sebastian Lague's Create a Game series and everything works fine except for the music. I don't know the cause of issue but while in gameplay scene another theme just starts playing, same thing happens when I restart the game and this also happens in Sebastian's finale version of the game so I can't find the answer there. I didn't really try anything since I don't have an idea what cause of the issue may be, so I decided to write here and maybe someone will know the answer. Thanks in advance!

Audio Manager:

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum AudioChannel { Master, Sfx, Music };

    public float masterVolumePercent { get; private set; }
    public float sfxVolumePercent { get; private set; }
    public float musicVolumePercent { get; private set; }

    private AudioSource sfx2DSource;
    private AudioSource[] musicSources;
    private int activeMusicSourceIndex;

    public static AudioManager instance;

    private Transform audioListener;
    private Transform playerT;

    private SoundLibrary library;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnLevelFinishedLoading;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnLevelFinishedLoading;
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

            library = GetComponent<SoundLibrary>();

            musicSources = new AudioSource[2];
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                GameObject newMusicSource = new GameObject("Music source " + (i + 1));
                musicSources[i] = newMusicSource.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
                newMusicSource.transform.parent = transform;
            }
            GameObject newSfx2Dsource = new GameObject("2D sfx source");
            sfx2DSource = newSfx2Dsource.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            newSfx2Dsource.transform.parent = transform;

            audioListener = FindObjectOfType<AudioListener>().transform;
            if (FindObjectOfType<PlayerInput>() != null)
            {
                playerT = FindObjectOfType<PlayerInput>().transform;
            }

            masterVolumePercent = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("master vol", 1);
            sfxVolumePercent = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("sfx vol", 1);
            musicVolumePercent = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("music vol", 1);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (playerT != null)
        {
            audioListener.position = playerT.position;
        }
    }

    public void SetVolume(float volumePercent, AudioChannel channel)
    {
        switch (channel)
        {
            case AudioChannel.Master:
                masterVolumePercent = volumePercent;
                break;
            case AudioChannel.Sfx:
                sfxVolumePercent = volumePercent;
                break;
            case AudioChannel.Music:
                musicVolumePercent = volumePercent;
                break;
        }

        musicSources[0].volume = musicVolumePercent * masterVolumePercent;
        musicSources[1].volume = musicVolumePercent * masterVolumePercent;

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("master vol", masterVolumePercent);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("sfx vol", sfxVolumePercent);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("music vol", musicVolumePercent);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    public void PlayMusic(AudioClip clip, float fadeDuration = 1)
    {
        activeMusicSourceIndex = 1 - activeMusicSourceIndex;
        musicSources[activeMusicSourceIndex].clip = clip;
        musicSources[activeMusicSourceIndex].Play();

        StartCoroutine(AnimateMusicCrossfade(fadeDuration));
    }

    public void PlaySound(AudioClip clip, Vector3 pos)
    {
        if (clip != null)
        {
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(clip, pos, sfxVolumePercent * masterVolumePercent);
        }
    }

    public void PlaySound(string soundName, Vector3 pos)
    {
        PlaySound(library.GetClipFromName(soundName), pos);
    }

    public void PlaySound2D(string soundName)
    {
        sfx2DSource.PlayOneShot(library.GetClipFromName(soundName), sfxVolumePercent * masterVolumePercent);
    }

    IEnumerator AnimateMusicCrossfade(float duration)
    {
        float percent = 0;

        while (percent < 1)
        {
            percent += Time.deltaTime * 1 / duration;
            musicSources[activeMusicSourceIndex].volume = Mathf.Lerp(0, musicVolumePercent * masterVolumePercent, percent);
            musicSources[1 - activeMusicSourceIndex].volume = Mathf.Lerp(musicVolumePercent * masterVolumePercent, 0, percent);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private void OnLevelFinishedLoading(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode sceneMode)
    {
        if (playerT == null)
        {
            if (FindObjectOfType<PlayerInput>() != null)
                playerT = FindObjectOfType<PlayerInput>().transform;
        }
    }
}
```

Music Manager:

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MusicManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private AudioClip mainTheme;
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip menuTheme;

    private string sceneName;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnLevelFinishedLoading;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnLevelFinishedLoading;
    }

    void PlayMusic()
    {
        AudioClip clipToPlay = null;

        if(sceneName == "Main Menu")
        {
            if(clipToPlay == null)
            clipToPlay = menuTheme;
        }
        else if(sceneName == "Gameplay")
        {
            if(clipToPlay == null)
            clipToPlay = mainTheme;
        }

        if(clipToPlay != null)
        {
            AudioManager.instance.PlayMusic(clipToPlay, 2);
            Invoke("PlayMusic", clipToPlay.length);
            Debug.Log(clipToPlay.length);
        }
    }

    private void OnLevelFinishedLoading(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode sceneMode)
    {
        if(sceneName != scene.name)
        {
            sceneName = scene.name;
            Invoke("PlayMusic", .2f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think `Invoke` takes arguments.  So you Invoke PlayMusic OnLevelFinishedLoading but then Invoke PlayMusic again in PlayMusic but this time with the new scene clip.

1st - Invoke is evil & I am shocked there is anyone still teaching it.

2nd - Come up with a different function name for each.  It just seems as if PlayMusic will just be continually invoking itself.

This is all in MusicManager BTW.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that